# Ruby TK GUI Development - Creating Labels from an Array

Tags: ruby, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I want to develop a to do list using Ruby TK GUI development.  I am trying to run a loop through my array of tasks to do.  I can't find an example or way to display an unknown amount of labels.  Any help is greatly appreciated, along with constructive criticism.


This doesn't display anything  the way it works, but with my prior knowledge to Ruby, this is the only way I can think of creating this.

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

root = TkRoot.new {title "Josh's ToDo List"}
content = Tk::Tile::Frame.new(root) {padding "3 3 12 12"}.grid(:sticky => 'nsew')
TkGrid.columnconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1; TkGrid.rowconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1

@todo_list = ['Go to the Store','Get Gas']

$date = TkVariable.new; $todo = TkVariable.new; $display = TkVariable.new
f = Tk::Tile::Label.new(content) {text 'To Do:'}.grid( :column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'we'); 
Tk::Tile::Entry.new(content) {width 7; textvariable $todo}.grid( :column => 2, :row => 1, :sticky => 'we' )
@todo_list.each {|task| Tk::Tile::Label.new(content) {textvariable task}.grid( :column => 2, :row => 2, :sticky => 'we');}
Tk.mainloop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple actually, you are using 'textvariable' which has to be a predifined global variable (like $todo, $date, and $display) in your $todo_list.each block, just change 'textvariable' to 'text'

```
 @todo_list.each {|task| Tk::Tile::Label.new(content) {text task}.grid( :column => 2, :row => 2, :sticky => 'we');}
Tk.mainloop
```